Registering for a free event, Civi is still presenting payment pane and user can't check out unless credit card is entered
Civi  5.72.0, php 8.2, CiviDiscount 3.8.11, Drupal 10.2.4
I have an event that has 100% discount code, even though the total is $0.00 Civi is asking for a credit card and won't process without.
This is also occurring when I have a free event with no discount code required.
Shouldn't a free event (or zero sum event due to discounts) bypass the payment panel?

Can you try the patch to see if it fixes your problem? Or you will need to wait till 5.73 is released

Thanks you, Pradeep. I have applied the patch but it is still requiring a credit card for zero total registrations. Do you know when 5.73 is expect to release? I have a hard go-live date of 5/1.

5.73 will be released on 1 May 2024 as per https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/release/blob/master/README.md
